# Convert MMM-YY string into Sortable Date Format

Tags: mysql, date-formatting, sql-date-functions

So I've gone around the houses a bit with this and not got it to work...

I have a SELECT query which contains a VARCHAR column (alloc_mth) with dates in the MMM-YY format (e.g. Jan-15) which I want to be able to ORDER BY in my query. In order to do so, I need to convert to a recognised date format. I've been following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139051/sql-converting-string-mmm-yy-to-date) but I'm struggling to get it to work.

My SELECT query is as follows...

```
SELECT `alloc_mth`, SUM(`line_cleared`), SUM(`line_count`), (SUM(`line_cleared`)/SUM(`line_count`))*100 as `Fill` 
FROM `allocHist` 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY CAST('1.' + `alloc_mth` AS DATETIME) ASC;
```

The end result of this is that the grouping and sum works fine but the date format and sorting doesn't...
[image]

Should this work or am I missing something?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: You're not using periods to delimit your dates.  You're using dashes.  Try `CAST('1-' + alloc_mth AS DATETIME)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the expression,

```
'1.' + `alloc_mth`
```

You are performing addition on strings, which in mysql will evaluate to `1`. The way to concatenate strings is with `concat(str1, str2)`. However, that should be unnecessary in this case.

You want to convert to a date with str_to_date.

```
order by str_to_date(alloc_mth,'%b-%YY')
```

Comment: Thanks for putting me  on the right track. That was just what I needed.