# 3 Letter Month Abbreviation to Date

Tags: sql

I have a list of months formatted with the 3 letter abbreviation followed by the last 2 numbers of the year.
For example, this current month would be SEP22. I need to find a way to turn this from a varchar into a date/datetime value, pointing to the first day of the month.

So, if I have 'SEP22', I need to get the output of September 1st, 2022 as a date/datetime object.

I can find a lot of data on turning the datetime value or numeric month into the abbreviation, but not the other way around.

I know I can make a giant case statement, but I was wondering if there's an easier method to read this type of data.

Any and all help is appreciated.

EDIT: I know the data is in the current century, I know where the data comes from and when it started being collected, all of this data has been collected in or after August 2013 (AUG13).

Comment: How do you know it's 2022 and not 1922?  Also what RDBMS the syntax varies  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139051/sql-converting-string-mmm-yy-to-date or oracle `SELECT to_date('AUG09','MONYY') FROM dual;`  not all SQL is the same sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    CAST(
        LEFT(StringDate, 3) -- e.g. SEP
        +' 1 20' -- assumes 21st century
        + RIGHT(StringDate, 2) -- e.g. 22
        AS DATE
    ) AS ActualDate
;
```

Comment: This is T-SQL but should get you on the right track if you're using another DBMS.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I've marked it as a solution.

Comment: It could be as simple as Select try_convert(date,stuff('Sep22',4,0,'20'))  ...  SQL Server will assume the 1st of the month.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server:

```
convert(date, '01 ' + LEFT('SEP22', 3) + ' ' + RIGHT('SEP22', 2), 6)
```

When SQL Server converts the date from a string with a 2-digit year, the cutoff is at 50:

```
declare @myMonth table (
  mo varchar(5)
)
declare @i int = 0

while @i < 100
begin
  set @i = @i + 1
  insert @myMonth
  values ('SEP' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(5)), 2))
end


SELECT mo
, convert(date, '01 ' + LEFT(mo, 3) + ' ' + RIGHT(mo, 2), 6)
FROM @myMonth
```

For Oracle:

```
TO_DATE('01' || 'SEP22', 'DDMONYY')
```

For Oracle, all of the dates are after 2000:

```
CREATE TABLE MYMONTH (
  MO VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL
)
;

INSERT INTO MYMONTH (MO)
SELECT 'SEP' || SUBSTR('0' || CAST(N AS VARCHAR2(5)), -2)
FROM (
  SELECT (0 + ROWNUM) N
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 100
)
;

SELECT MO
, TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01' || MO, 'DDMONYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
FROM MYMONTH 
;
```

Comment: Your SQL Server approach could be as simple as   try_convert(date,stuff('Sep22',4,0,'20'))

Comment: For 2000-2050, that's true.  What if the input is SEP75?  The OP was unclear regarding which century to use for which 2-digit year values.  I didn't want to assume the first 2 digits of the year are always 20.  My response stuck to how the RDBMS would answer that part of the question.  If the OP provides more clarity, I may revise my answer.

Comment: I think the real question is why the data modeler or application developer decided to use MMMYY format to store dates.  I assume that's just nonsense the OP is being forced to deal with.

Comment: Over the years I've had to consume some horrible data from various sources...  You just roll with it and create a solution.